# Propensity score matching in SPSS

Tags: spss, propensity-scores

A practical question. When performing propensity score matching in SPSS v25, I get a separate sheet with all the cases and pairs. However, a small number of cases have propensity variable blank (10 of 1800 cases) and some more have match id blank (50 out of 1800).

What to do with these cases with blank match id and propensity value? Do I include them in subsequent analyses?

To be more precise, I analysed 1000 cases from 2 periods 6 years apart. During these 6 years, staff that makes some decisions has change and I wanted to find whether there are more or less unnecessary procedures perfomed on these cases. However, two populations differ on such a large scale that some kind of standardisation is necessary. So I performed PSM with 5 variables, and got pretty similar groups. Although the difference is singificant if I include all the cases from PSM table or only those with non-missing matchID, I cannot find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. All records with blank/missing matchID are non-matched and should be excluded from the analysis. They are however included in the sheet just if you want to analyse also non-matched cases...